# Button with 9-patch image background doesn't stretch correctly

Tags: android, android-view, nine-patch, android-styles

I have a problem with custom background for button. There's my 9-patch:
[image: resulting image]

Same in Draw 9-patch:

[image: in Draw 9-patch]

And, finally, result on device's screen:

[image: result on screen]

And that's the code, describing my button:

Layout:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        style="@style/button"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
</style>
```

`@drawable/button`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_test"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

File name of drawable in res folders is button_test.9.png

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work? Thank you.

Comment: could be a compilation issue. clean and rebuild ?

Comment: also, you should put the drawable in the item directly :`<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_test"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove bitmap tag inside item tag, add android:drawable attribute within item tag

Answer (score 0):

try this 9-patched image:

[image]

hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a transparent perimeter with at least one pixel thickness around your image.
See the sample images in official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

Try this image.
[image] (Make sure that you are saving it with .9.png extension)

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3063975) using backticks for non-code, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why